# Macros for Wordpress, creating subdomains out of registrations for current domain

Tags: user-registration, subdomains, configuration, automation

I have a website: atmydevice.com and I want people to register on the website.  That's easy.  But I want the registration to create an automatic subdomain like ac.atmydevice.com with a different theme and a second username and password.  And I want the subdomain once registered to have certain characteristics that only now I can put in place individually.

I have to do this all handmade right now.  Creating the user on atmydevice.com, uploading the subdomain with wordpress on bluehost.com and uploading the theme for the subdomain, configuring the subdomain with script and configurations on the subdomain for the new user, adding them both as users to atmydevice.com and to their subdomain  xxx.atmydevice.com.

Is there macros for WordPress?  I really need some help with automation.  I'm planning my subdomains for thousands.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) installation with a wildcard subdomain configuration.

Comment: I got multisite but what is wildcard subdomain configuration?  Also my sites when people register are not activating even though emails are being sent to activate the site

Comment: Set up Multisite to use subdomains for network sites. A [wildcard subdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains) can direct all unconfigured subdomains to WordPress, such that you don't have to manually create new subdomains for each site. You shouldn't be needing to "upload a theme" for each new site, either, unless every sub-site is using a different theme. I'm not sure what to tell you about about the "site activation" issue. Maybe review the tips on the [ask] page and edit your question with more information!

Comment: I think I have to add the wildcard *.domain.ext as a DNS record. How do i do this?

Comment: I think BlueHost gives you [cPanel access](http://atmydevice.com/cpanel), just go to "subdomains" and point `*.atmydevice.com` at your WordPress installation. Otherwise, most hosts support wildcard CNAME entries - in your DNS control panel, add a new CNAME record pointing `*.atmydevice.com` to `atmydevice.com` - how that's actually done depends on the specific DNS interface (i.e. cPanel's, or a domain registrar's, or some custom BlueHost one). While they *should* support CNAME entries, they might not, in which case you should create an A entry pointing to `atmydevice.com`'s IP address.